# Why does postfix on AWS give me "Invalid MAIL FROM address provided"? I have production access

Tags: email, postfix, amazon-web-services

I'm running the postfix mail server on my AWS box. My domain is `mydomain.com`. 
I have set up virtual mapping such that emails sent `myuser@mydomain.com` should be forwarded to `target-user@gmail.com.com`.

I have used Amazon SES to verify certain email addresses. When emails from those verified addresses are sent to `myuser@mydomain.com`, it properly forwards them to `target-user@gmail.com.com`. However, when emails from non-verified addresses try to do the same, it fails. It fails even though I have been granted production access to Amazon SES.

Below are the logs from my postfix during this failure. You can clearly it says `Message rejected: Email address is not verified`. Why? And how can this be resolved?

```
Oct 24 01:25:49 ip-172-XX-XX-XX postfix/smtpd[20215]: connect from mail-yh0-f50.google.com[209.85.213.50]
Oct 24 01:25:49 ip-172-XX-XX-XX postfix/smtpd[20215]: CCC61FA93: client=mail-yh0-f50.google.com[209.85.213.50]
Oct 24 01:25:49 ip-172-XX-XX-XX postfix/cleanup[20236]: CCC61FA93: message-id=<CAN+z9YGrkNunh9ueJ-i=9eNpV5QAK97Z9muVHATfACbG7gWgYw@mail.gmail.com>
Oct 24 01:25:49 ip-172-XX-XX-XX postfix/qmgr[20120]: CCC61FA93: from=<random@gmail.com>, size=2295, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 24 01:25:50 ip-172-XX-XX-XX postfix/smtpd[20215]: disconnect from mail-yh0-f50.google.com[209.85.213.50]
Oct 24 01:25:50 ip-172-XX-XX-XX postfix/smtp[20237]: CCC61FA93: to=<target-user@gmail.com>, orig_to=<myuser@mydomain.com>, relay=ses-smtp-us-west-2-prod-14896026.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com[54.69.13.41]:25, delay=0.47, delays=0.21/0.01/0.12/0.13, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host ses-smtp-us-west-2-prod-14896026.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com[54.69.13.41] said: 554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified. (in reply to end of DATA command))
Oct 24 01:25:50 ip-172-XX-XX-XX postfix/cleanup[20236]: 3D156FA95: message-id=<20141024012550.3D156FA95@mydomain.com>
Oct 24 01:25:50 ip-172-XX-XX-XX postfix/qmgr[20120]: 3D156FA95: from=<>, size=4332, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 24 01:25:50 ip-172-XX-XX-XX postfix/bounce[20238]: CCC61FA93: sender non-delivery notification: 3D156FA95
Oct 24 01:25:50 ip-172-XX-XX-XX postfix/qmgr[20120]: CCC61FA93: removed
Oct 24 01:25:50 ip-172-XX-XX-XX postfix/smtp[20237]: 3D156FA95: to=<random@gmail.com>, relay=ses-smtp-us-west-2-prod-14896026.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com[54.187.176.120]:25, delay=0.11, delays=0/0/0.1/0, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host ses-smtp-us-west-2-prod-14896026.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com[54.187.176.120] said: 501 Invalid MAIL FROM address provided (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
Oct 24 01:25:50 ip-172-XX-XX-XX postfix/qmgr[20120]: 3D156FA95: removed
```

Answer (score 6):

I recieved this related(?) message

```
Mail command failed: 501 Invalid MAIL FROM address provided
```

While mailing with githubactions `dawidd6/action-send-mail@v2` using SES.

Changing the from email from `user@domain.com` to `"User" <user@domain.com>` fixed it

Comment: Thank you, this was my exact issue!  Note that you will also need to put it all in quotes for your workflow/action YAML: `from: '"User" <user@domain.com>'`

Comment: thank you! worked like a charm

Answer (score 4):

Production SES access doesn't give you unrestricted ability to send mail from any address.  It only raises limits on the number of e-mails you can send, etc., as per [Limits in Amazon SES](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/limits.html).

Maybe you were confused by [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html), which states "Emails can be sent only from verified email addresses or domains."  This is also true for Production SES access; maybe it wasn't in the past.  See the "Sender and Recipient Limits" section of [Limits in Amazon SES](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/limits.html).

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue `"Invalid MAIL FROM address provided (in reply to MAIL FROM command))"`.

Following is the work around

1. Check from postfix logs which "From" address postfix is using.
2. MAP that from address in `"/etc/postfix/generic"` like following.

   root@xyz xyz@YourSesDomain.com
3. Run `postmap /etc/postfix/generic`
4. Make sure that you have following in your /etc/postfix/main.cf

   smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
5. Reload postfix service

Comment: That's an amazing solution for crontab, POSTFIX and Amazon SES in combination. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another note on the answer above (which is 100% correct) - you can mostly get around this problem by setting a Reply-To address in your mail headers instead of relying on the From address.